# Decoder for the XMLs inside an APK

Tags: android, xml, apk

APK files are .zip files and we can decompress them, that's the easy part!
but i found that the XML files inside are not normal XML files (binary maybe?) my question is how to decompile these files to the original form??

I don't wanna use any tools, I just need to know the formal definition of these strange XML (binary?) files in order to be able to decode them!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why would you want do "decode" those?

Comment: I need to know the hierarchy of the layout files

Comment: along with the resource ids

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to look at the code of those tools like android-apktool. Format of the structure of binary xml files is not well documented anywhere.
 One must infer from the source code of tools like android-apktool, aapt, etc.

Comment: how those guys did it anyway!

Comment: by looking at android source code. Specifically if you have a look at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h, you will find how data is stored in binary format